# R Shiny renderTable - freeze columns

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, datatable, conditional-formatting

Looking for some help adding freeze frames to a `renderTable` in R Shiny. I'm using `renderTable` instead of `DT` package `renderDataTable` because I have a dataframe of over 400 columns. `DT` was choking on the rendering, but `renderTable` seems to work very quickly.

Here is an example:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(DT)
  
  fruit <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana")
  num <- c(54, 25, 51, 32)
  Oct2020 <- c(10, 15, 20, 25)
  Nov2020 <- c(5, 7, 10, 15)
  Dec2020 <- c(7, 9, 12, 17)
  Jan2021 <- c(6, 9, 2, 0)
  Feb2021 <- c(15, 30, 12, 2)
  Mar2021 <- c(6, 7, 8, 10)
  
  data <- data.frame(fruit, num, Oct2020, Nov2020, Dec2020, Jan2021, Feb2021, Mar2021)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 1, numericInput("numFruit", "Number of Fruit", value = 10)),
      column(width = 1, div(style = "margin-top: 25px", actionButton("btnUpdate", "Update")))
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
      div(style = 'height: 200px; width: 500px; overflow: scroll; font-size: 90%', align = "left", tableOutput("dt_Fruit"))  
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt_Fruit <- renderTable(data, striped = TRUE, hover = TRUE, bordered = TRUE)
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

I'm looking for the ability to freeze the first two columns, **fruit** and **num**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two questions are very different. I reply to the second one. Please open another question for the first one.

The solution I propose makes use of the **jQuery** plugin **freeze Table**.

```
library(shiny)

widetbl <- t(iris[1:40,]) # a wide table for the illustration

js <- HTML(paste0(c(
  '$(document).on("shiny:value", function(evt) {',
  '  if(evt.name === "wideTable") {',
  '    setTimeout(function() {',
  '      $("#wideTable").freezeTable({',
  '        fastMode: true,',
  '       columnNum: 2',
  '      });',
  '    }, 0);',
  '  }',
  '});'
), collapse = "\n"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/yidas/jquery-freeze-table/dist/js/freeze-table.min.js"
    ),
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  br(),
  tableOutput("wideTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["wideTable"]] <- renderTable({
    widetbl
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]